# PlayFramework FakeApplication Cannot connect to inmemory H2 database [default]

Tags: playframework, database-connection, runtime-error

I'm trying to create some test users for my JUnit test, and I'm getting this error.

Cannot connect to database [default]

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void before() {
        running(app, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for(Integer num = 0; num < 100; ++num) {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.username = "testUser" + num;
                    user.setPassword("pwd");
                    user.dateCreated = new Date();
                    user.save();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So my application.conf config is plain and stupid

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
```

And it's get populated correctly in fakeApplication() helper.

I have no memcached, and I've tried to populate additionalConfiguration of fakeApplication() with bare hands. It haven't helped anyway.

I dont think that starting EbeanServer and generate ddl manually is a good idea, but it works in my case. I think that it has to work out of the box following default framework docs without such nightmares.

I dont know what to do, maybe I've missed something ?

Help me please.

Comment: Well, I've managed that running my fakeapp with start() and stop() helpers works fine... I'll look for/report an issue to playframework repo.

Comment: Did you ever report this issue? Was there any resolution?